# Choosing design pattern to consume SOAP webservice in a C# client application

Tags: c#, web-services, design-patterns

I have a C# client application and I need to consume two SOAP webservices that are hosted in external webMethods environment that exposes same functions (same name, same parameters and datatypes) i.e.

Web Service 1 - ManualLoadProduction

Function 1 - LoadMontlyData(string Month)

Function 2 - LoadYearlyData(string Year)

Web Service 2 - ManualLoadConsumption

Function 1 - LoadMontlyData(string Month)

Function 2 - LoadYearlyData(string Year)

I have added web reference for both of the web  services in my C# solution. I can simply call the functions separately, however, I need build a layered solution. How should I design/implement the solution

Comment: Please be more specific about "layered solution". What's wrong with just calling the methods as-is? Also, I hope you're using "Add Service Reference", and not "Add Web Reference". That should not be used for new development.

Comment: If you want a layered solution wrap the methods in a wrapper class, and have that implement an interface that you use to call the wrapped methods throughout the rest of your project.

Comment: Thanks @John-Saunders, I realised misspelt username but it won't let me change for next 30 days.
I need to create wrapper classes to wrap around the webservices however, being a beginner I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan-Byrne, would you possibly paste a short example as being a beginner i am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an interface that you can use through out you application. This allows the consuming code to be dependent on a contract rather than a specific implementation.

```
public interface IServiceWrapper{

    Data  LoadMontlyData(string Month);
    Data LoadYearlyData(string Year);
}
```

Here is one implementation for ManualLoadProduction wrapper. Wrapping the service method allows you to wrap other functionality around the service calls, such as extra validation or object mapping.

```
public class ManualLoadProductionWrapper: IServiceWrapper{

      public Data LoadMontlyData(string Month){
         //implementation calls service method
      }

       public Data LoadYearlyData(string Year){
         //implementation calls service method
      }
}

public class ManualLoadConsumption: IServiceWrapper{

      public Data LoadMontlyData(string Month){
        //implementation calls service method
      }

      public Data LoadYearlyData(string Year){
       //implementation calls service method
      }
}
```

Comment: It's also possible to have the service itself implement the interfaces. The auto-generated classes are declared `partial`, just add another declaration specifying interface implementation.

Comment: Its better to have the client have its own interface to have it be more decoupled from the service.

Comment: Sure, that's what I meant, make the auto-generated SOAP proxy classes implement client's local interfaces.